# What does the asterisk do in Google Search

Tags: google-search, search-operators

What is the difference between `bark*`, `bark` and `bark *` in Google Search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the details about Google search operators can be found [here](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/136861?hl=en). The purpose of the `*` is to fill in the blank.

> Add an asterisk within a search as a placeholder for any unknown or wildcard terms. Use with quotation marks to find variations of that exact phrase or to remember words in the middle of a phrase.

**"`a * saved is a * earned`"**

Examples:

- `bark` returns anything about the word "bark"
- `bark*` returns anything that has bark as a prefix, including bark itself
- `bark *` returns any phrase containing "bark "

Comment: Thank you. But what is the difference between returns anything about the word "bark" and returns any phrase containing "bark "?

Comment: @eirini The one with the asterisk is looking for instances of common and continuous phrases with that word in it, particularly highlighting the words that follow after "bark". The one without asterisk is more general and doesn't particularly care about word association around "bark".

Comment: This answer is obsolete. The reference was updated. It no longer includes the `*` operator.